# How to increase disk size for a Xen Virtual Machine?

Tags: disk-space, xen

How can I increase the disk capacity of an existing Xen VM? I've just run out of space.

Answer (score 1):

What kinds of backed do you use?

If you use LVM, it's quite easy to extend the size.

If you use file backend, my suggestion is that create a new file that has larger capacity. Then use dd to copy all data from the original file to the new one.

After doing this, the "hard disk" of Xen DomU is larger. You can then change the file system's size in side of DomU.